# Image.asset in Expanded FittedBox widgets show blank

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use `Image.asset` inside `FittedBox` in `Expanded` widget. But it always shows black screen.

```
Scaffold(
 body: Column(
    children: [
     Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
       fit: BoxFit.contain,
       child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
      ),
    )
  ]
 )
)
```

If I use it without `Expanded` and `FittedBox` then it works

```
Scaffold(
 body: Column(
   children: [
    Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png')
  ]
 )
)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what's the point to use FittedBox here?

Comment: @Nagual I just figured it out that `Image.asset` also have `fit` property.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. It seems I was overusing the widgets. I have to simply use the `fit` property of `Image.asset` instead of using another parent widget `FittedBox`. My code reduces to:

```
Scaffold(
 body: Column(
  children: [
   Expanded(
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain)
   )
  ]
 )
)
```